# Where is FileNotFoundException in C++/CX?

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

The method [StorageFolder.GetFolderAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderasync.aspx) is supposed to throw `FileNotFoundException` but I cannot find it anywhere. How am I supposed to handle the exception throw by it?

Comment: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @tkausl That is for C# API, not C++ API. There is no such thing as `System.IO` namespace in C++/CX.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please try adding `using namespace System.IO;` to your C++ file to see that the documentation is unreliable. Otherwise, I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: Ugh, the documentation is lousy.  [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699896.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++/CX version of the documentation for [StorageFolder.GetFolderAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderasync.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) does not account for exception handling, as implemented in C++/CX (see [Exceptions (C++/CX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh699896.aspx)):

> The **Platform** namespace defines distinct exception classes for the most common HRESULT values; all other values are reported through the [**Platform::COMException**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh710414.aspx) class.

The [System Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx) is part of the .NET framework. As such it is not available to C++/CX code. The exceptions listed in the documentation for `GetFolderAsync` are only thrown, when the function is called from .NET.

When called from C++/CX, `GetFolderAsync` reports failure through `Platform::COMException`. The equivalent for a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` is an exception, with the `HRESULT` set to `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)` (0x80070002).

A C++/CX exception handler should catch `Platform::COMException` (or [Platform::Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh755825.aspx)), and check the [Exception::HResult property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh763371.aspx) to identify the specific exception type.

---

References:

- *[HRESULT_FROM_WIN32 macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680746.aspx)*
- *[System Error Codes (0-499)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx)*